# Android Studio の仮想デバイス上で画面のスクロールが出来ない

Tags: java, android, android-studio

## 問題点

プログラムを実行して仮想デバイスの画面をスクロールしようとしても画面がスクロールされません。(スクロールバーは表示されているので、スクロールの機能は反映されてると考えています。)
画面の途中からスクロールさせたいと考えています。
例)　YouTubeのコメント欄だけスクロール出来る様な感じです。

オレンジの範囲をスクロールしようと考えています。

[image: オレンジの範囲をスクロールしようと考えています。]

## 試したこと

複数のTextViewを1つのGridLayoutで挟んだ後にScrollViewでまとめて囲った。

**activity_sub1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

*中略*

 <GridLayout
 *中略*
 </GridLayout> 

<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".SubActivity1"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="143dp"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
            android:background="@drawable/grid_border"
            android:columnCount="8"
            android:rowCount="30"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="104dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnSpan="2"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="食事①" />
    
　　　　　　*中略*  TextViewが以降続く　

   　　　</GridLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 解決できました

## スクロールすると、ScroleView外のGridLayoutと被ってしまった原因と修正点

【原因】
ScrollViewの
android:layout_height="match_parent"
としていて範囲を絞っていなかったので、コード上ではScroleView外のGridLayoutが範囲内にあった。

【修正点】
ScrollViewの
android:layout_height="match_parent"
を
android:layout_height="315dp"
に変更。(これでスクロール時にScroleView外のGridLayoutと被らなくなった)

## スクロールが途中で止まってしまった原因と修正点

【原因】
GridLayoutのconstraintを画面トップから250dpの位置で固定していたため、上手くスクロール出来ないことが分かりました。

【修正点】
ScroleView内のGridLayoutの中の
android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
を消去しました。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

*中略*

 <GridLayout
 *中略*
 </GridLayout> 

<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="315dp"           //変更点
        tools:context=".SubActivity1"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="143dp"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　// android:layout_marginTop="250dp"を消去
            android:background="@drawable/grid_border"
            android:columnCount="8"
            android:rowCount="30"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```